# Microsoft Service Broker external activator perfomance

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, service-broker

How can I push Microsoft SSB External activator to consume more messages from my queue.

I already set `<Concurrency min="1" max="128" />` but still not getting
enough TPS from this.

Any help ?

Comment: My suggestion is to get rid of the Microsoft external activator and directly call the related SQL scripts.  Little more work but you can do so much more.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I tried that but the problem here is I cannot call a webservice to post the message to my external application. The queue disables itself once I try to do web service call, weird.