# CLR stored procedure activated by a broker queue to post to a webservice

Tags: sql-server, clr, sqlclr, service-broker

I want to call a CLR inside a service broker queue activated store procedure but doing this causes the queue to be disabled - `POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING (STATUS = ON)`.

Basically, the CLR just calls a webservice to post the data it recieves.

Is there a permission or something I need to do first ?

Comment: Does your SQLCLR Stored Procedure work when called outside of the Service Broker process? Is it signed? Did you create the Asymmetric Key from the Assembly, and the Login from the Asymmetric Key, and then grant that Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @srutzky - Yes, the SQLCRL works outside of the Service Broker process but not signed. Do I need to get it signed for this to work ?

Comment: Whether it fixes the problem or not, it is the much preferred means of allowing external access by SQLCLR code. I would start by signing, creating the key, then the login, and granting the permission. Then turn TRUSTWORTHY OFF for that database. Then try again and if it doesn't work, try to get an error message. You might need to grant EXECUTE on the SQLCLR Stored Procedure to Service Broker Login.

Comment: @srutzky - seems to be a solution I see everywhere and I tried it but  got another error: 
`The activated proc '[dbo].[ProcessOrders]' running on queue 'App01.dbo.InstTargetQueue' output the following:  'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.ProcessOrders`

Comment: @srutzky - I just enabled the `trustworthy` settings on the database to get past it, not a good solution though.

Comment: I am confused by the lack of specific references in the last two comments. What seems to be the solution that you see everywhere? And enabled TRUSTWORTHY to get past what, specifically?

Comment: Ah...the recommended solution of signing, creating the key, login, and granting the right permissions didn't work but for testing purposes, I turned on TRUSTWORTHY settings on the database which obvously works but not recommended - thanks!

Comment: Meaning, you didn't already have TRUSTWORTHY ON? Then how did the stored proc work when run outside of Service Broker? Was it in the same DB?

Answer (score 1):

> `The activated proc '[dbo].[ProcessOrders]' running on queue 'App01.dbo.InstTargetQueue' output the following: 'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.ProcessOrders`

This error indicates that the queue is configured with a stored procedure that was dropped from the database, perhaps. Can you double check that the procedure exists? Perhaps you have a typo, eg. an extra space, in the queue configuration? Run `select * from sys.service_queues` and double-check that the activated procedure name is exactly what you expect. Run `select * from sys.procedures` and make sure the procedure exists and is named as you expect.

To answer your question about CLR: first and foremost I would urge you to move the webservice calls outside of the database. Monitor the queue with an external process service, and post the web service call from your process, not from inside the database.

If you insist on calling webservices from SQLCLR, then this is what you need to know:

- CLR procedures require EXTERNAL_ACCESS on the assembly to be allowed to call web services
- Activated procedures run in an 'execute as' sandboxed environment, see [Why does feature … not work under activation?](http://rusanu.com/2006/01/12/why-does-feature-not-work-under-activation/)
- The sandboxed environment prevents EXTERNAL_ACCESS

So you need to exit the sandboxed environment of the activated procedure, and this can be done either by marking the database as TRUSTWORTHY, or by signing the procedure, see [Signing an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/). But right now your problem seem to be a simple name mismatch.

If you keep your web services inside SQLCLR (and I strongly discourage that) then please read about [`Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) (the second applies to an external process as well, not only SQLCLR).

Comment: I have the store procedure signed with correct name but I keep getting that error in the server logs. Immediately, I made the database TRUSTWORTHY - it started working! weird.
Also, I initially tried the EA but for reasons, wasn't fast enough to push the data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804220/microsoft-service-broker-external-activator-perfomance